# Facebook Application Group Limitations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-game-groups

I am investigating building an application that will heavily leverage Facebook's app/game groups.   During my prototyping I noticed the following limitations:

**1) Number of Groups** - There seems to be a limit on the number of groups an application may have, that limit seems to be tied to the number of users participating in the application.   For example with 1 user participating in the application, I can only create one group.  If I add a few more user I can add several more groups.  Does anyone know if the specific limitations are documented.   I cannot seem to find them and it would be good to know what they are so I can develop my application around these constraints.

2) **Number of Groups a User can be invited to** - When I try to add a user to more than 5 groups (through consecutive API calls), I get the following error:

```
OAuthException: (#4002) The attempt to invite the user to the group failed.
```

Does anyone know if there is a limitation with how many groups a user can be a member of within a given application?   Is the limitation based on time, for example can a user join up to 5 groups every hour, etc??   If there is such a limitation are the constraints documented somewhere?

Thanks in advance for the help.

--Steve

Comment: Hey Stephen, did you ever find an answer to this? Thanks.